# splitting window in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to split my web application window in two columns as 30% and 70% like we do in html,what should i do??

Comment: If you know how to do this in Html, the probably you can use the same trick in asp.net as well because it also has the same thing. You can look at master page here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx and use it further

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Naturally, everything you can do in HTML you can do in an asp.net application. So anything from FRAMESET to floating divs will work.

Comment: even if i use <frameset cols="30%,70%"> its giving me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the exact same HTML code..

Note, you can change to dynamic percentages too by using outer divs, using tables (*gasp!*), etc. CSS purists might not like tables, but they still work in every browser out there.

```
.left{
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
}
.right{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
```

Comment: It's not about being a "CSS purist", it's about doing things the way they are intended to do, instead of hacking your way through a shady standard to make it look decent for *most people*.

Comment: Tables work consistantly on most if not all browsers.  Unfortunately CSS does not always.